# Displaying multiple data Fields in Bound field of grid view

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I have the following sql query that I want to display in a gridview, basically to fields joined.

How can I do this?

```
SELECT 
--RTRIM(C.CustomerFirstName) + ' ' + LTRIM(C.CustomerLastName) as CustomerFullName,
C.CustomerCompany,
C.CustomerPosition, 
C.CustomerCountry, 
C.CustomerProvince, 
C.CustomerContact,
CP.ActionDate, 
CP.ProductCode,
CP.CustomerEmail
     FROM tblCustomers C
    INNER JOIN 
    tblCustomerProducts CP ON 
C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail
     ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

this is the html for the grid view. Basically I want CustomerFirstName and CustomerLastName in one field

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="231px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <Columns>
            **<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerFirstName" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerLastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />**
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCompany" HeaderText="Company/Organisation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerPosition" HeaderText="Position" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCountry" HeaderText="Country" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerProvince" HeaderText="Province" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerContact" HeaderText="Contact" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerEmail" HeaderText="Email Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionDate" HeaderText="Action Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCode" HeaderText="Product code" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: check the answer....will work for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want  [is to use an](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) `<asp:templatefield>`instead of the `<asp:boundfield>`

Step 2 in the link above shows one way of using the templatefield. Here is another:

```
<columns>
    <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%#Eval("CustomerFirstName")%>, <%#Eval("CustomerLastName")%></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp:BoundField>
....
</columns>
```

I added the `<div>` and `,` to show you can use basic text and html in your `<ItemTemplate>`.